# Position of boxes fixed to top with css

Tags: html, css

I'm implementing a css to my list of boxes (named as agile board) fixed to top, currently I've 5 boxes something like this:

```
<div class="nits-agile-board">
    <div class="ibox">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nits-agile-board">
    <div class="ibox">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nits-agile-board">
    <div class="ibox">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="nits-agile-board">
    <div class="ibox">
    </div>
</div>
```

I've defined the css something like this:

```
.nits-agile-task {
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative;
    width: 350px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

In my console it looks something like this:

[image: console]

Now while doing so I get my output something like this:

[image: CSS bug]

Now while going through other questions in the community I changed my css to:

```
.nits-agile-task {
    display: inline-block;
    position: fixed;
    width: 350px;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

But now it overrides all the boxes and only last box is seen, remaining boxes are not shown, when I see in my console HTML of all the boxes are present over there.

[image: CSS override bug]

and the console looks like this:

[image: console 2]

How can I achieve this.

Comment: please share complete console or complete HTML

Comment: @NagaSaiA added console screenshot, please check

Comment: did you try float:left on ibox  - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/xYayLL

Comment: because they all are available in DOM and grouped on top of each other, float:left will display them side by side which will solve your problem

Comment: @NagaSaiA this isn't helping me out, I tried placing `float` in `.nits-agile-task` and tried adding to `.ibox` still the same.

Comment: add vertical-align:top to your boxes without the fixed position

Comment: Yes it worked. thanks a ton.:)